# convert string numbers separated by comma to integers or floats in python

Tags: python

I am very super new at Python and I've run into a problem.  I'm trying to convert a string of numbers into an int or float so that I can add them up.  This is my first question/post.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
total = 0
s = '2, 3.4, 5, 3, 6.2, 4, 7'

for i in s:
    total += int(i)
print total
```

I get the errors:

```
      *3 
      4 for i in s:
----> 5     total += int(i)
      6 print total

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to split the string

```
total = 0
for i in s.split(','):
    i = float(i) #using float because you don't only have integers
    total += i
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to split the string at the commas using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Then, convert them to floats (I don't know why you're using `int` when you say that you want to convert them to "an int or float").

```
total = 0
s = '2, 3.4, 5, 3, 6.2, 4, 7'
for i in s.split(','):
    total += float(i)
print total
```

Personally, I would prefer to do this with a generator expression:

```
s = '2, 3.4, 5, 3, 6.2, 4, 7'
total = sum(float(i) for i in s.split(','))
print total
```

The reason what you're doing doesn't work is that `for i in s` iterates over each individual character of `s`. So first it does `total += int('2')`, which works. But then it tries `total += int(',')`, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: [comprehension -> generator expression]

Comment: @DSM Are they not also called "generator comprehensions"?

Comment: Not officially.  Amusingly, I think Hettinger's original name was "generator comprehension", but Tim Peters suggested "generator expression" instead, and that's the one which was officially adopted.  See the history in [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: @DSM Well, I'll be darned. Okay, changed.

Comment: FWIW, I often use `replace(',', ' ').split()` because it also allows the numbers in the string to simply be space-separated -- so a shorter ones like `'2 3.4 5 3 6.2 4 7'` and `'2,3.4,5,3,6.2,4,7'`also work.

Answer (score 3):

You have a string of comma separated *float* values and not *int*. You need to `split` them first and then add them. You need to cast it to `float` and not `int`

```
total = 0
s = '2, 3.4, 5, 3, 6.2, 4, 7'

for i in s.split(','):
    total += float(i)
print total
```

Output will be `30.6`

Answer (score 1):

How about this? (^_^)

```
In[3]: s = '2, 3.4, 5, 3, 6.2, 4, 7'
In[4]: s = s.replace(",","+") # s = '2+ 3.4+ 5+ 3+ 6.2+ 4+ 7'
In[5]: total = eval(s)
In[6]: print(total)
30.6
```

Comment: Don't use `eval` .. It is very wrong to do so. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html . Use `import ast; total = ast.literal_eval(s)` instead

Comment: @BhargavRao: `ast.literal_eval()` won't evaluate the `+` operators. But you *can* use `sum()` on the output of evaluating `s` as literals: `sum(ast.literal_eval(s))`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, for the insight. Hopefully liyuanhe211 will edit his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach.

```
total = 0
s = '2, 3.4, 5, 3, 6.2, 4, 7'
lst = s.split(',');
for i in lst:
    i = float(i)
    total += i
print total
```